# Support for EIP1271 smart contract signatures for 0x nft swaps?

Tags: 0x

Does 0x's nft swapping protocol plan on supporting eip 1271 smart contract signatures for the new nft swap protocol? We want to use gnosis safe (multisig) and other smart contract wallet (argent) to bid and sell nfts on 0x

Answer (score 0):

For smart contract order makers, you will want to use the presigned/on-chain orders pattern. See: https://docs.0x.org/nft-support/guides/signing-orders/on-chain-orders

Comment: what about for buying? i.e. a multisig/safe *buying* an item that has been listed

Comment: Buying an order doesn't require a signature from the taker.